# Range of sum of vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S,T$ be elements of $L(V,W).$ Show that the range$(S +T)$ is a subspace of range$(S)$ + range$(T)$.

I tried applying the definition of range, but I wasn't sure how to proceed after that.

Comment: For every $v\in V$, $(S+T)v=Sv+Tv\in range(S)+range(T)$.

Comment: No, the sum of two vector spaces $S+T$ is the set $S(v_1) + T(v_2)$ for all $v_1, v_2$ in V.

Comment: That's right. Now put $v_1=v_2$ and read my comment again.

Comment: But you are assuming $v_1 = v_2.$ What if they are not? How do you know that the statement is true then?

Answer (score 0):

Are you stating that you want to show that is just a subspace, or a vector 
subspace? I would recommend clarifying this aspect. On the subspace aspect of
this problem, we do see that
$$range(S+T) = \{i | \exists v. (S+T)v = i\}.$$

we know that $$Sv \in range(S) \wedge Tv \in range(T) \implies
Sv+Tv \in range(S) + range(T) \implies range(S+T) \subseteq range(S) +
range(T).$$
To prove the vector space properties, we simply want to consider its
linearity over scalar multiplication and vector addition. I assume that you
would find these rather straightforward to prove given the nature of linear
transformation. Then you would have the result that it is a vector subspace.